# Sending same data to two different thread using message queue (single message queue) in C

Tags: c, multithreading, ipc, message-queue

Is to  possible to send the same data from sender thread to two different receiver threads using message Queue mechanism. Receiver thread should receive same data. As per my understanding Shared memory with synchronization mechanism is proper solution for such scenario. But I was wondering if we could do it using message queue as if one thread pop the data other thread won't have anything to receive from the system message queue.

Comment: Push the same data down two queues?

Comment: Jon,with two queue it will be feasible but can we do it using single queue?

Comment: Why?  What do you gain? If you leave the data on the queue, what would stop the same thread from getting that one piece of data twice?  If you're going to send the same data to all queues, it's a *lot* easier - and less bug-prone - to use N queues - one per thread - than it is to create some sort of complex queue that distributes the same data to all queues.

Comment: Message queues are associated to receivers, not senders. They are used to buffer inputs from possibly several senders. As you already noticed, if you want to share same data, you can use shared memory.

Comment: If your message queue supports peeking (like Unix `recv`), it can be done, if you can synchronize the recv operations so they alternate.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick,I am novice to the IPC concepts can you please share a piece of code which will explain peeking mechanism or any link which explains it in detail